# Evaluating $\int_0^1 \int_0^x \left( 1 - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2 + \cos(2\pi t)}\right) dt dx$

Tags: real-analysis

> Is there a nice way to calculate $$\int_0^1 \int_0^x \left( 1 -
>  \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2 + \cos(2\pi t)}\right) dt dx$$ ?

I had the idea to switch the order of integration but I am a bit clueless, since the integration variable occurs as a bound in the inner integral. I also was thinking about some differentiation or integral trick, but I am not sure. Has anyone an idea how to solve this? Or is there no other solution than just calculating everything?

Comment: You can apply the Leibniz Integral Rule

Comment: @Savitr Could you please elaborate a bit more on this?

Comment: Use integration by parts to reduce it to one integral.

Comment: @TheGeekGreek See the explanation of rule here-https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zbWihK9ibhc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your function
$$
t\mapsto 1-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2+\cos(2\pi t)}
$$
is invariant under the mapping $t\mapsto 1-t$, your integral equals
$$
\frac{1}{2}\iint_{[0,1]^2}\biggl(1-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2+\cos(2\pi t)}\biggr)\,dt\,dx.
$$
Now, the integrand is independent of $x$, so this equals
$$
\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1\biggl(1-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2+\cos(2\pi t)}\biggr)\,dt=\cdots=\biggl[\frac{1}{2\pi}\arctan\biggl(\frac{\sin(2\pi t)}{2+\sqrt{3}+\cos(2\pi t)}\biggr)\biggr]_0^1=0.
$$

Comment: Sorry, but at the moment I do not quite see, why invariance under $t \mapsto 1 - t$ implies that I can integrate the function on the square.

Comment: Your original integral can be viewed as an integral in half the square, cut at the main diagonal. Does that help? It could help to draw a picture.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the leibniz Integral rule to the inner integral. The equation will be simplified to

$$\int_0^1(1-\frac{\sqrt3}{2cos2\pi x})dx$$

And Now I think you can solve that pretty easily.

Leibniz Integral Rule-https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zbWihK9ibhc